# Take data from form, process and return to the same form

Tags: php

I am aware I have no vailidation or sanitziation. This will be added :D

I currently have a php form which requests the following information:

- Avg. salary
- number of employees
- Pension Uptake PCT
- Pension Contributuin PCT

Which is then submitted, and proccessed by a file called SSESC.php (code will be below).

It should then return, the computed data to the field Total Employee contribution (`$TEC`) and Total Savings (`$NISAVING`)

I can get the data passed to the SSEC.php file, and it is processed (tested by echo) but I am unable to get the data back and displayed on the form.

Im attempting to save the data into a session, and then return and refill the form. Im returning from the script by using `<?php header ("location: form.php");?>`. this works but the form is not filled in. I will include the snippets below from the form.

SSESC.php code

```
<?php header ("location: form.php");?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SSEC-Process</title>
</head>
<?php
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB');
$Average_Salary = $_POST["Average_Salary"];
$EMPNUM = $_POST["EMPNUM"];
$PUPCT = $_POST["PUPCT"];
$PCPCT = $_POST["PCPCT"];
$TEC = "";
$NI_save = "";

$employeepension = $PCPCT/100;
$pensionuptake = $PUPCT/100;

$TEC = $Average_Salary*$employeepension*$EMPNUM*$pensionuptake;
$combi = $TEC*13.8/100;

$NI_save =  money_format('%.0i', $combi);

$_SESSION["TEC"] = money_format('%.0i',$TEC);
$_SESSION["NISAVE"] = $NI_save;

?>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Form Snippets

```
<input id="TEC" name="TEC" class="Label" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?=  $_SESSION['TEC']?>"/> 


<input id="NI_save" name="NI_save" class="label" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?=$_SESSION['NISAVE']?>"/>
```

Thanks in advance.
Steve.

Comment: Some code is missing in your post. Where is the Form snippet being included into the main file?

Comment: Did you add `session_start();` at the top of your code? Both in the form as in the process script? Enable `error_reporting` to see what went wrong.

Comment: This makes no sense, you redirect to form.php in the first line?!

Comment: @Bojan Kogoj, yeah, that was part of what i was doing, wrong, i rmoved the html part of the php file, and added session start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not starting the session handler. You should have
   `session_start();` on top of both of your scripts. (Both in this script and in form.php. Right at the top)
2. Why are you outputting HTML if you are not showing any, and redirecting to another file anyways?
3. Remove the unnecessary HTML on the processing script, and move the `header()` call to the bottom of the processing script.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to write the standard tag (`<?php echo`) because the short-end tag is not always enabled. So you have to write:

```
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['TEC']?>"
```

Have you called `session_start` before this statements?

Try this first and after do a `var_dump` to test if the value has been setted right.

Comment: Thanks, I missed Sesion_start, other than that all good thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your form with:

```
<input id="TEC" name="TEC" class="Label" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['TEC']?>"/> 


<input id="NI_save" name="NI_save" class="label" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['NISAVE']?>"/>
```